# Jordan measurable and Lebesgue measurable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Question

> If $A$ has volume and if $\lambda$ is defined as
>   $$\lambda=\inf\{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}v(S_i)| S_1,S_2,... \text{ is a countable cover of $A$ by open rectangles}\},$$ then $v(A)=\lambda$.

I find that this is related to measure theory.

But in my text book (*Elementary classical analysis* by Marsden), there is only volume of bounded set by Riemann integration and definition of measure zero, no Lebesgue integration.

I can't under stand how to link countable cover with finite rectangle.

So it is hard to show that question. Help me.

Comment: I.m not familiar wth that book but it seems  you need a better one, in which measure theory is covered in detail. The standard by which other texts have been judged has been the texts on real and complex analysis bt RUDIN.

Comment: @user254665 would you explain that question with measure theory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that if $W$ is a finite set of bounded open rectangles and $t$ is a bounded open rectangle, then for any $r>0$ there is a finite set $T(t,W,r)$ of bounded open rectangles such that $$(1)... \cup T(t,W,r)\supset (t  \backslash  \cup S).$$ $$(2)... \sum_{x\in T(t,W,r)}v(x)<r+v(t  \backslash  \cup S).$$ $$ (3)...\sum \{v(a\cap b): a,b\in T(t,W,r)\land a\ne b\}<r.$$ Now if  $\mathbb S=\{S_i:i\in N\}$ is a set of bounded open rectangles (where it does not matter whether $S_i=S_j$ for $i\ne j$), take any $r>0$ and let  $W_1=\{S_1\}.$ Now for $i\in N,$ let $$W_{i+1}=W_i\cup T(S_{i+1}, W_i,2^{-i-1}r).$$  Then $\mathbb S^*=\cup_{i\in N}W_i$ is a countable set of bounded open rectangles with $$(1)... \cup S\subset \cup S^*.$$ $$ (2)...\sum_{u\in S^*}v(u) <r+\sum_{u\in S}v(u).$$ $$ (3)... \sum \{v(a\cap b):a.b\in S^*\land a\ne b\}<r.$$

With regard to your Q, consider a bounded $A.$ From the above paragraphs, we can find,for any $r>0,$ a countable cover $S^*$ of $A$ by bounded open rectangles  such that $$\sum \{v(a\cap b):a,b\in S^*\}<r$$ $$\text { and } \sum_{a\in S^*}v(a)<2 r+\lambda.$$ We would like to show, by contradiction, that there does NOT exist $x>0$ such that the Riemann integral $\int_{\mathbb R^2} \chi_A(y)\;dy$ is less than $-s+\lambda.$

I don't have time to finish this. I'll come back later .